# Netty : execute CompletableFuture callback in I/O thread pool

Tags: netty

Netty 4.1.2.Final

The [wiki](http://netty.io/wiki/thread-model.html) says

> Regardless of its transport and type, Netty's all upstream (i.e. inbound)
>   events must be fired from the thread that performs I/O for the channel
>   (i.e. I/O thread). All downstream (i.e. outbound) events can be
>   triggered from any thread including the I/O thread and non-I/O
>   threads. However, any upstream events triggered as a side effect of
>   the downstream event must be fired from the I/O thread. (e.g. If
>   Channel.close() triggers channelDisconnected, channelUnbound, and
>   channelClosed, they must be fired by the I/O thread.

Now I have a `CompletableFuture`,  I want to let the callback to be executed in netty's I/O thread.

```
future.thenAcceptAsync((Map<String, String> map) -> {
  // ...
});
```

The [thenAcceptAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAcceptAsync-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) accepts an `executor` parameter, **how to send  `executor` parameter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the EventLoop itself is an Executor so you can use :

`channel.eventLoop()` and use it as argument.